# drag and snap Ajax or asp control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

im looking for a free version of the following http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx and wondered if anyone knew of anything that existed something that you can drag and snap panels in to other panels then save the layout of these panels preferably to a database. If they is no free versions anyone can think of (i have looked and cannot find anything :/ ) how easy would it be to program such a Ajax or asp control? and how could i go about doing so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, ASP.NET already has this through its web parts.  It's pretty similar to this control.  The Telerik one looks nicer, but the web parts controls already have most of the features that Telerik offers.

You can also customize them too.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Look at jQuery UI.  Specifically their interactions area: http://jqueryui.com/demos/  It's real easy to implement.

The part you will need to supply is the storage of where everything goes.

We use their drag and drop, I didn't even know Telerik had one although we have Telerik all over our projects.